# position: fixed; doesn't seem to fix element to top?

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue where the `position: fixed;` property doesn't seem to fix the element to the top of the page. I've tried a variety of things to get it work, including:

- Adding a `z-index` property of `9999`
- Containing all other elements within a single element wrapper (`.fixed-wrapper`)
- Placing the element both before/after `.fixed-wrapper` in my markup.

The `position: fixed;` property is applied to the `.header-fixed` element. The website is located [here](http://www.arkway.co/d).

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated! :)

**Update #1:** The funny thing about it is that it seems to work a little bit, until all the page elements fully load and then it breaks.

Comment: "the element to the top of the page"... which element exactly?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: did you add the rule: top:0; ??

Comment: By top do you mean not at the top of the page (vertically / top:0) or it's being hidden by other elements and isn't `on top` ?

Comment: @BoltClock Chrome, Firefox seems to work fine and have no other browsers to test on. @gvee '.header-fixed`. @Danield yes I did.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I mean it's not fixed to the top of page, not that it's not on top.

Comment: Your `.header-fixed` is fixed to the top of the page as you intended, which is why your content scrolls beneath it.  You have an image that overflows out of it because your heights of certain child div's are not set correctly.  In addition, there is mismatch between the top of each section so it does not coincide with the bottom header of the fixed header.  You need to isolate the problem and build a fiddle, post some relevant HTML and CSS...

Answer (score 1):

Add some `z-index` to `.fixed-wrapper`.

Example :

```
.fixed-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```